# How to display router link text in a other page in angular11

Tags: angular11

In this Messagelist there a five messages,I just want display this messages in a another page I have added router links. Ex :If I click “sssss” I want display that “sssss” in other page.

Answer (score 0):

first the add the queryparams

```
<a [routerLink]="['user']" [queryParams]="{name: 'test'}" </a>
```

In the second page,you will read the queryparams value and render the HTML.

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }  
this.route.queryParamMap.subscribe(params => console.log(params));
```